# How to display time in format 12:07 rather than 12:7?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a userform and in the date box it shows 12:7 when I would like it to show 12:07.

It does show when the time is, ex 12:10

I have watched tons of YouTube videos and looked at the documents Microsoft has posted but I still don't understand how to make it work.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  
  Txtdatebox.Value = Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now)
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much!

Comment: To whom do you thank, please?

Comment: @FaneDuru sorry I thought I had tagged you thank for the quick response ! you are awesome

Comment: No need to tag me if you comment **on my code answer**... After the code a 'add comment' would be the one to be accessed. :) No problem. Everybody learns the community rules... And in this regards, we here, when somebody place a convenient code, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will understand that the answer worked... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Txtdatebox.Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm")`